# Let $T=\{17\}, U=\{6\}, V=\{24\}$ and $W=\{2,3,7,26\}$. In which of these four different universes is the statement true?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

sLet $T=\{17\}, U=\{6\}, V=\{24\}$ and $W=\{2,3,7,26\}$. In which of these four different universes is the statement true?

a) $(\exists x)(x\,odd\implies x>8)$

b) $(\exists x)(x\, odd\wedge x>8)$

c) $(\forall x)(x\,odd\implies x>8)$

d) $(\forall x)(x\, odd\wedge x>8)$

For a) I said $T, U, V$ and $W$. (because we can even choose an $x$ which isn't odd and the implication will be true)

For b) I said $T$. (This is because it should have both conditions, unlike with implication)

For c) I said $T, U, V$. (There is 7 which doesn't satisfy the implication in $W$, so the rest is true because forall and exists have the same meaning if the set have only one element)

For d) I said $T$ (both conditions again, for all elements, that's why)

Is this true ?

Comment: Yes it is. Why downvote?

Comment: Everything is correct? O

Comment: Nah, I don't really know what to add in answer. :) Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers and argumentation are spot-on. There's nothing more to add really. Cheers!